# Webpack-dev-server how to remove default routing for react app?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using webpack-dev-server for running my reactJS application. I want to implement own router (for learning purposes), but webpack-dev-server intercepts pathname of url and return 404 error. How to remove or fix this ? I just want to processing urls' pathname by own route component and remove processing of router with webpack-dev-server.

My webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/app.js",
    module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question, but maybe you want to set [`historyApiFallback` to `true`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback)?

Comment: @Tholle yes, that's it! Thanks a lot, if you add your comment as answer - I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [`historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback) to `true` and the server will respond with the `index.html` page instead of `404`.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```